# Can I use roslyn with Windows Metro or RT apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, roslyn

I am wondering if it is possible to create a Metro style (or even Windows RT on ARM) app that makes use of the Roslyn libraries?

The roslyn libraries are not listed in the namespaces available to metro, but can I just include the roslyn dlls with my app? (Or do they use APIs that aren't available from metro?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Roslyn is using API's that are not available to Metro apps. However, it is an interesting idea. The Roslyn team has not yet even tried to make the codebase Metro friendly.

Answer (score 0):

From Metro Apps you can use modules that use the restricted APIs. But the Windows App Certification Kit would fail the certification process because of which you would not be able to upload the app to the Windows Store. Distributing such apps would require the user to install a developer license in order to run the app.